# ALPS metadata for all Spring-MVC Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I've a question about the ALPS support in spring hateoas/data rest. It seems that the ALPS metadata are only exposed if you have a spring data rest repository. So my question is why is there only a support for the spring data rest repository and can I enable it for all spring mvc controllers? Is there any example to expose the ALPS metadata for all controllers?

Maybe I haven't understood the conept of ALPS...

Greets

Meleagros

http://spring.io/blog/2014/07/14/spring-data-rest-now-comes-with-alps-metadata

Comment: Hi, did you figure out how to do this? thanks

Answer (score 5):

This only partially answers the question, but Oliver Gierke answered the following in the comments on the blog post linked above:

> Because it relies on the knowledge of which kinds of links you expose,
>   how you name them and which HTTP methods are supported. With a plain
>   Spring MVC application all of this is out of control of the framework,
>   hence we can't provide it out-of-the-box.
>
> However, Spring HATEOAS contains API to write custom Alps descriptors
>   so that you can expose additional metadata that describe your
>   controllers manually.