# Customize alps generation in Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data, customization, spring-data-rest

I am mixing SDR (Spring Data Rest) with custom controller like define in:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers

With this to keep HATEOAS link between SDR and custom Controller:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_resourceprocessor_interface

Everything works find except for handling ALPS metadata. There an automatic ALPS generator in Spring data Rest http://localhost:8080/profile and I don't know how to include custom metadata which is not handle by SDR

UPDATE:
please see author response in the comments of this article: https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/14/spring-data-rest-now-comes-with-alps-metadata but I don't know how add ALPS through Spring Hateoas...

similar SO post: [ALPS metadata for all Spring-MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469923/alps-metadata-for-all-spring-mvc-controller)

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot add anything to alps, you can only add customs links to your API. If you what go white good documentation for your API which is mixing Spring MVC and Spring data rest, it is better to choose another way of doing this. For example, you can use [Spring rest docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-restdocs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need "technical" api description. I need to parse attribute to get objet description. Not really need human description like in asciidoctor (spring rest docs)